# Software Engineering Internships

Tags: internship, software-development

I am an undergraduate senior in CS looking to apply for software engineering internships for summer 2017. I also have plans to enroll in my school's one year CS MEng program after graduation, but acceptances don't come out until March. Will this disqualify me from internships that are looking for students who will be undergraduate/masters students after summer 2017? If possible, how can I express my future plans on my resume?

Comment: I'm not familiar with education, as I got kicked out thrice myself. What is a senior internship in this case? Edit: unless you mean you are senior in the sense of being old, then I understand.

Comment: If you don't get accepted, will you be joining a master's program somewhere else?  Or would you consider going into the workforce?  If you're potentially going to enter the workforce, then you probably wouldn't want a summer internship, you'd probably be looking for a full-time job starting in the summer.  If you're going to be in a master's program somewhere and the only question is where, then an internship would likely make sense.

Comment: I'm confused; what are you worried will disqualify you? I'm not seeing anything wrong with your situation.

Comment: Senior here means I'm in my fourth year of university. I will also be looking at master's programs elsewhere. Many large tech companies, such as Google/Apple/Facebook, require individuals looking for summer internships to still be students after the internship ends. I am currently looking for 1-year masters programs and acceptances for those programs usually don't come out until spring. However, by that time, it will be too late to apply for these internships.

Comment: Ah, in the Netherlands we don't consider what year a student is in. Cool, learn something new every day)

Answer (score 3):

**Generally assume requirements for *anything* are on the lenient side**, whether the requirements are an exhaustive list of skills you do not have, more years of experience than you have been working, or a student status you ambiguously qualify for. Only the company can answer for sure and *usually* they ask for their ideal applicant, and widen the net as people inquire.

A resume is usually about completed accomplishments, not future plans. But, if you have finalized plans to begin a program, indicate it as: "X University Y program, expected completion 20xx." Your acceptance is, of course, an accomplishment and if you are willing to chain yourself to your future plan when you send your resume out, then you should include the program.

Your application should of course be transparent about your status but there is a little bit of an art to this. **You have two responsibilities: making sure they are aware of your enthusiasm for the position, and making sure they are aware of your gray-area status so they can make a decision.** Guess which one comes first?

Comment: I have found that the first paragraph is generally correct. Good answer.